# NSMutableArray changes to NSCFString

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, nscfstring

When I try to add some string values to a `NSMutableArray` it shows following exception.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

**here is my code:**

```
NSMutableArray *pTitle = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

**code for adding object:**

```
[pTitle addObject:txtTitle.text];

[dataBase setObject:pTitle forKey:@"Title"];
```

All I need to revoke the `NSMutableArray`.
How can I resolve this...
Thanks in advance for your Valuable helps...

Comment: search that pTitle is declared as NSString somewhere in class.

Comment: maybe you can show a little more code? because in what you provide it should be correct. Maybe after the init of pTitle you somehow assign it to some other dataType?

Comment: Are you using ARC? What code is in between the creation and usage of the array?